# GridDB - Running Insert query in griddb shell returns an error [240008:SQL_COMPILE_COLUMN_NOT_FOUND]

Tags: sql, ubuntu, wsl-2, dml, griddb

I've created a table in griddb using this query:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name STRING
);
```

When I try to insert a record using insert query it returns this error:

> D20332: An unexpected error occurred while executing a SQL. : 
> msg=[[240008:SQL_COMPILE_COLUMN_NOT_FOUND] Column not found (name=John
> Doe) on updating (sql="insert INTO tbl1 (id, name) VALUES (1, "John
> Doe")") (db='public') (user='admin') (appName='gs_sh')
> (clientId='ddd01cd4-3370-4a12-a62f-ce3a652540d5:2')
> (source={clientId=3, address=127.0.0.1:54084})
> (address=127.0.0.1:20001, partitionId=246)]

This is my insert query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (id, name) VALUES (1, "John Doe");
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try single quotes instead, `'John Doe'`. (Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, e.g. a column named `John Doe`.)

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a similar error and followed the comment by [jarlh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3706016/jarlh)

Using a single quote helps fix the error.
Try using;

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (id, name) VALUES (1, 'John Doe');
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES (1, 'John Doe');
```